# Data binding in ng-repeat in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am a Angular JS beginner and this might be a very silly question but i am finding difficulty with this. I have the following code written in angular js to display the list of products with the categories.

```
  <html>
     <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">      </script>
        <script>
           var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);
           myApp.controller('myController',function($scope){
           $scope.welcome = "WELCOME TO STORE"
           $scope.products = 
           {
             "ProductDetails": [
               {
                 "category": "Favorites",
                 "data": [
                   {
                     "price": "10",
                     "description": "Favorites product1 demo description",
                     "name": "Demo product1"
                   },
                   {
                     "price": "13",
                     "description": "Favorites product2 demo description",
                     "name": "Demo product2"
                   }
                 ]
               },
               {
                 "category": "Stationary",
                 "data": [
                   {
                     "price": "10",
                     "description": "Favorites product1 demo description",
                     "name": "Demo product1"
                   },
                   {
                     "price": "13",
                     "description": "Favorites product2 demo description",
                     "name": "Demo product2"
                   },
                   {
                     "price": "13",
                     "description": "Favorites product2 demo description",
                     "name": "Demo product2"
                   }
                 ]
               },
               {
                 "category": "Food",
                 "data": [
                   {
                     "price": "10",
                     "description": "Favorites product1 demo description",
                     "name": "Demo product1"
                   },
                   {
                     "price": "13",
                     "description": "Favorites product2 demo description",
                     "name": "Demo product2"
                   },
                   {
                     "price": "13",
                     "description": "Favorites product2 demo description",
                     "name": "Demo product2"
                   }
                 ]
               }
             ]
           }
           });
        </script>
     </head>
     <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="myController">
           <h1>{{welcome}}</h1>
           <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="categories in products.ProductDetails">
                 <h3> {{categories.category}}</h3>
                 <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="item in products.ProductDetails.data"></li>
                    <p>{{item.name}}</p>
                    <p>{{item.description}}</p>
                    <p>{{item.price}}</p>
                 </ul>
              </li>
           </ul>
        </div>
  </html>
  </body>
```

i am using ng-repeat to loop through the list of items and and display it. i am bit confused about using multiple ng-repeat and how to bond the data. i need the output similar to the image below.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: replace `ng-repeat="item in products.ProductDetails.data` to `ng-repeat="item in categories.data` in inner <li> `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of the element that has the ng-repeat as having its own local scope.  Think of it like a block of code inside {} for an if statement or something like that.  Note the closing `li` tag below, you must be inside the block created by the `li` tag to be able to reference `item`.

You also want to repeat over `categories.data`

```
<li ng-repeat="item in categories.data">
                    <p>{{item.name}}</p>
                    <p>{{item.description}}</p>
                    <p>{{item.price}}</p>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
ng-repeat="item in products.ProductDetails.data"
```

To

```
ng-repeat="item in categories.data"
```

[here is plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kAhGbKVTBh6prA1Mcw1X?p=preview)

Comment: provide proper plunker please

Answer (score 0):

Here Is the problem

```
      <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="categories in products.ProductDetails">
             <h3> {{categories.category}}</h3>
             <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in categories.data"></li>//Set Categories
                <p>{{item.name}}</p>
                <p>{{item.description}}</p>
                <p>{{item.price}}</p>
             </ul>
          </li>
       </ul>
```